# Rough trend calculation and approximation error

Tags: statistics

In many cases calculating trend by using least-squares method is best decision. But sometimes it is overabundant. What I need is just to know, whether trend is positive or not.
Can I use such approach (difference in weight coefficient) and how to determine it's approximation error?

($x_1*1$ + $x_2*2$ + ... + $x_n * n$) - ($x_1*n$ + $x_2*(n-1)$ + ... + $x_n * 1$)

Examples:

Negative

```
19  17  11  1  4  4  6  3  2  2    => -283
```

Positive

```
0  0  1  3  1  1  7  5  6  12      => 182
```

**Update**

Calculation using this approach and least-squares approach

[image]

Comment: By `x2*n-1` did you mean $x_2\times(n-1)$ or $(x_2\times n)-1$?

Comment: I mean x2×(n−1)

Comment: MathJax markdown added to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint-** Write your suggested formula in vector form:
$$\begin{align}
w_1&=\pmatrix{1&2&\cdots&n}^T\\w_2&=\pmatrix{n&n-1&\cdots&1}^T\\
x&=\pmatrix{x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_n}^T\end{align}$$
Then you would get:
$$\text{trend}=w_1^Tx-w_2^Tx=(w_1-w_2)^Tx$$
where
$$(w_1-w_2)^T=\pmatrix{1&3&5&\cdots&2n-1}-\pmatrix{n&n&\cdots&n}$$
My impression is, this couldn't be reliable enough for seeing a trend.

Comment: I have taken about 5000 example data-sets from Database and made calculations using my rough approach and least-squares method. Interesting, that they have almost 100% correlation. Moreover `roughFormula result divided by 165 equals least-squares method result`. Sorry for my poor math, but I think it's very interesting.

Comment: @PavelTkackenko As you see in the expression of $w_1-w_2$, the $\pmatrix{n&\cdots&n}$ is just a bias and can be ignored in trend detection. So you are left with $\pmatrix{1&\cdots& 2n-1}$. This weight vector doesn't look much beneficial over $w_1$. I suggest you just work with $w_1$ and not $w_1-w_2$ to see what I'm saying.